# Cosmos DB .net throws error when trying to connect from linux docker container

Tags: .net, docker, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently migrating a MongoDB backend to Cosmos DB. 
Connection, reading and writting is working without problems from windows hosts.

As connecting string I'm using (like provided in the getting started section on azure)

```
string connectionString = 
  @"mongodb://aaa:bbb@ccc.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@ddd@";
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
  new MongoUrl(connectionString)
);
settings.SslSettings = 
  new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
```

If I compile the application for a linux docker container, I get this errors on runtime (local and on azure):

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM09JMTH8P61", Request id "0HM09JMTH8P61:00000004": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/aaa.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/aaa.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Sockets on this platform are invalid for use after a failed connection attempt.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowMultiConnectNotSupported()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ConnectAsync(Socket socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2020-06-05T22:14:26.2687880Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-06-05T22:14:26.2687882Z" }] }.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToList[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at backend.Services.UserService.Get() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/backend/Services/UserService.cs:line 41
   at backend.Controllers.UsersController.Get() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/backend/Controllers/UserController.cs:line 36
   at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequest[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

```
root@4ebf2742cd2d:/app# nslookup aaa.mongo.cosmos.azure.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
aaa.mongo.cosmos.azure.com    canonical name = cdb-ms-prod-westus1-bbb.cloudapp.net.
Name:   cdb-ms-prod-westus1-bbb.cloudapp.net
Address: 40.112.xx.xx
```

Tested images:

- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/runtime-deps:latest
- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/runtime-deps:5.0-alpine
- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/runtime-deps:5.0-focal

I'm out of ideas what the problem could be. Does somebody faced something familiar?

Thanks

Edit 1: In the meantime I installed an Ubuntu 20.04 VM to test it without docker, the same result. So there is something fishy when using linux as runtime.

Comment: Could it be that the port `10255` must be opened in a firewall? You can use `telnet ccc.mongo.cosmos.azure.com 10255` as a quick test. If you get a `Connect failed` there is no listener / a firewall between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of stupidity I used the current beta of MongoDB.Driver. Switching back to current stable version fixes the problem.

I submitted an bug report: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-3126